# The correct form of writing dates

Tags: word-choice

Should dates be written like this: "the 26th of April"?
This is how students of English write dates in local schools. (In Russia) .

Comment: Yes, they can be. Where are you using this?

Comment: For example,  "The 26th of April." With "Classwork" or "homework" under the date.

Comment: In the US or elsewhere? US dates are written month/day/year, whereas most of the world writes day/month/year

Comment: There are *many* ways to write dates in English; for school assignments, one should follow the school's guidance. When I was in primary school, we were told to write out the date as (e.g.) "April 26, 2021"; at university, the preferred format was "26 Apr 2021" but "04-26-2021" was also acceptable; now, at my employer, there is only the requirement that it be unambiguous.

Comment: No, not in the US. In Eastern Europe. Is my original example wrong?

Comment: In a sentence, you would _say_ 'It happened on the 26th of April', but you would probably write it as '26 April'. When putting the date at the top of a piece of work, it would be inappropriate to include _the_ and _of_.

Comment: Please note: 26 April 2000 is BrE. April 26th, 2000 is AmE. "The 26th of April was a beautiful day."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates can be written in lots of different ways, but I'd (educated in England) be surprised to see

> the 26th of April

as a heading. At my school, the norm was

> 26th April

(You wouldn't need the year, because that would generally be written on the front of your exercise book.)

Here's an example from one of my Chemistry exercise books:

[image: Beguine's A-level Chemistry book (from 2010) showing the date.]

I'd only include *the* and *of* if I were writing a date in a sentence.

> Her birthday party is on the 26th of April.

Comment: Thank you, BeginTheBeguine. I was taught that when announcing a date, writing "on the thirtieth of April" is formal. Writing "on the 10th of April" (with of without "th" doesn't matter) is ever very rare. if I am not announcing a date, if I write in my notebook "the thirtieth of April" or "the 30th of April" and add "classwork" or "homework" would these forms still be very formal? Does anything change if I announce a date and  just write today's date? You said you would be surprised to see the 26th of April.  if I write it in words "the twenty-sixth of April would it be formal?

Comment: (Caveat: I'm writing this based on everyday usage in the UK.) In a sentence, you should write "The event is taking place on the twenty-sixth of April". "The event is taking place on the 26th of April" is not uncommon, but is less formal, and would probably be corrected if you put it in an essay.

Comment: For a heading in a school book, or on an invitation in the format "You are invited to X. Date: 26th April, Location: Local swimming pool, Time: 2.30 pm", I would never put *the* and *of*. If you wrote "the 26th of April" or "the twenty-sixth of April" in your schoolbooks I would guess it was something you'd specifically been taught to do. Even in formal letters (in Britain) we'd tend to put "26th April 2021".(See here for an example: https://www.dailywritingtips.com/how-to-format-a-uk-business-letter/)

Comment: Thank you so much!